# Do we have an equivalent procedure to Training a custom container in Azure similar like GCP?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Do we have a similar approach in Azure as provided in below GCP link ?
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/custom-containers-training

Appreciate the assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not conventional as Azure has different ways to approach this problem, but it can be done and I've done it before using custom images.

[Here is the doc on custom containers.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-custom-docker-image)

Every pipeline step occurs within containers. If you look inside your Azure resources you will see a container registry dedicated for your AML instance. You can even download them and work on them locally if you have access. You can also push your own custom containers.

When you use your container (which is assumed to have some code in it that takes an input and trains a model), you specify your execution with the [InferenceConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.inferenceconfig?view=azure-ml-py&preserve-view=true).  You will be able to see the outputs and logs in the AML interface.

In [line ~67 here](https://github.com/BillmanH/learn-azureml/blob/main/config.py) you can see an example of using a custom environment in a pipeline script step. I'm using this to specify a runtime environment and then pushing my code into it at runtime, but you could easily modify this to create custom training step that mimics what's going on in the google doc.

Depending on your problem there may be easier ways to do train a custom model, but I feel that this answers OP's specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @billmanH. will look into it.!